# MySQL query based on SUM per month

Tags: mysql, join

The project is about a system where every X minutes of calls based on the given month its set a rate where multiplied by these calls result in the commission to be paid.

Example:
1 - 1000 mins = * 0.01 resulting in a $10 pay if made 1000mins or the equivalent if lower.
1001 - 2000 mins = * 0.02 resulting in a $20 pay if made 2000mins ...
2000+ mins = * 0.03, so if made 2500 in calls, commission would be $75

Is it possible to set a query for such math? Need to take in consideration user will be setting different time frames to search, for example, from 1 to jan to 15 march.

In JAN, if it was made 1500mins, I will have to display a daily report multiplying per 0.02
In FEB, if it was made 4000min, I will .... per 0.03
In MAR, if it was made 500min till the date queried, I will ... 0.01

It also, needs to take in consideration, user might be searching for jan 1 to 15 and even if it results in only 500min, the whole month should be taken in consideration for the calc.

Comment: Are these tiered?  Meaning, you pay $0.01 for the first 1000 minutes, $0.02 for the second 1000 minutes, etc.  Or, does it mean that if you have 1400 minutes, you will pay $0.02 for all 1400.

Comment: Also, can you provide your DDL?

Comment: You will pay 0.02 for all the 1400. Thanks

Comment: Hello, table structure is pretty simple. id|date|minutes|userid, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using mysql, perhaps you can do something like this?

```
select 
     mon,
     case
         when total_time <= 1000
              then total_time * 0.01
         when total_time > 1000 
          and total_time <= 2000
              then total_time * 0.02
         when total_time > 2000
              then total_time * 0.03
     end case as pay
from
    (select
         sum(minutes) total_time,
         extract(month from date) mon
     from 
         calls
     group by 
         extract(month from date)
    )
```